# How to perform matrix union and intersection?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Supposing using NumPy, given two matrixes `mat_A` and `mat_B`:

```
              value 
date                                                     
2020-10-16    49.78
2020-10-15    50.30
2020-10-14    50.44
2020-10-13    50.85
2020-10-12    51.42
...             ...
2014-01-08    45.25
2014-01-07    45.18
2014-01-06    45.19
2014-01-03    45.21
2014-01-02    44.95
```

[1711 rows x 2 columns]

```
              value
date                                                     
2020-10-16     95.0
2020-10-15     95.0
2020-10-14     95.0
2020-10-13     95.0 
2020-10-12     95.0
...             ...
2012-08-08    209.0
2012-08-07    209.0
2012-08-06    209.0
2012-08-03    209.0
2012-08-02    209.0
```

[1361 rows x 2 columns]

Is there an efficient way to get the following?

- the union between the `mat_A` and `mat_B`:

  - by using `date` as pivot
  - filling the symmetric difference between `mat_A` and `mat_B` with `value=None`
- the intersection between `mat_A`, and `mat_B`

Comment: It all depends on what module and related data-structure your matrices are in, but you haven't specified that. Generally speaking, it's possible with the right extensions (Python doesn't have native matrix support).

Comment: @martineau supposing NumPy

Comment: I've tagged your question according, perhaps someone will now be able to answer your question. Have you looked at `numpy`'s documentation, it's quite good…

Comment: Those look more like pandas dataframes than numpy matrix.

Answer (score 1):

To intersect you may use `intersect1d`

```
_, inter, _ = numpy.intersect1d(a[:, 0], b[:, 0], assume_unique=True, return_indices=True)
```

Which gives you indexes of `a` in `b` and vice versa. This one is pivoted.
And if you need not pivoted one then you may do it thrice

```
_, inter 1, _ = numpy.intersect1d(a[:, 1], b[:, 1], assume_unique=True, return_indices=True)

_, no_piv_inter, _ = numpy.intersect1d(inter1, inter2, assume_unique=True, return_indices=True)
```

For symmetric difference, there is `setxor1d`

```
diff = numpy.setxor1d(a[:, 0], b[:, 0], assume_unique=True, return_indices=True)
```

There is `union1d`. But it seems to do not work for your case because it does not return indexes. To join you may use `vstack` and `unique`.

```
v = numpy.vstack((a, b))
_, unique = numpy.unique(v[:,0], axis=0, return_index=True)
union = v[unique, :]
```

Then you may fill the difference

```
diff_idx = numpy.in1d(union[:, 0], diff, assume_unique=True)
union[diff_idx, 0] = None
```

I did not run all codes. Do not beat me for syntax errors. The idea should be correct.

This way is not efficient in terms of complexity. I believe that the data structure is wrong. For the requested operation hash table that is dict in python are preferable. But these numpyed operations supposed to be fast relative to loops.